# The navigation is borked in Chrome

Tags: bug, design

When I open the site in Chrome - either main or meta I get this:

[image: the top bar in chrome]

rather than this:

[image: the top bar in Firefox/IE]

I *think* this is the CSS used to display the elements in the list:

```
line-height: 1;
text-align: center;
color: #444;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
background-color: #fff;
min-width: 1010px;
```

Comment: See http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6114/can-we-please-back-out-the-toolbar-changes. Short version: the problem lies in some experimental features of the browser and there is a way to turn them off.

Comment: Dammit. I did search too (honest)

Comment: Looks like the descriptive terms you chose were different from John's. No worries.

Comment: Feel free to close/delete

Comment: Close rather than delete for the *next* person's sake...